# Strange application crash

Tags: c++, ubuntu-10.04

I have this C++ application running on a **Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.3 LTS** which is crashed and the reason really escapes me.

The method which exhibits failure is this one:

```
void
IoLogikCommunicator::processPacket(char const* data, WORD wSize)
{
  std::string message(data, wSize);
  std::stringstream ss(message);
  std::string token;

  std::vector<std::string> tokens;
  while (std::getline(ss, token, '#'))  // <- crash
    tokens.push_back(token);

  if (tokens[0] == "SENSORS")
      processSensorsPacket(tokens);
  else if (tokens[0] == "SELECTOR")
      processSelectorPacket(tokens);
}
```

According to the core dump, `data` content is valid and it is:

```
p data
$1 = 0xb7520214 "SENSORS#192.168.107.62#DI:00#ON#DI:01#ON#DI:02#ON#DI:03#OFF#DI:04#OFF#DI:05#OFF"

p wSize
$2 = 79
```

The content of `tokens`, at crash time, is `["SENSORS"]`, so the first element was parsed correctly.

What happens then is:

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x009de422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x009de422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0766a651 in raise () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#2  0x0766da82 in abort () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#3  0x076a149d in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#4  0x076ab591 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#5  0x076ae710 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#6  0x076aff9c in malloc () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#7  0x0070dc07 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x006e7d06 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x006e9f70 in std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x006c4274 in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

given the **SIGABRT** it seems that an assert() fails inside the malloc invocation, but what could be the reason? Of course, it was impossible for me to reproduce the bug: this method is invoked several times per second and the application crashed after 30 and more days of continuous running.

The very same data, then, is processed by another identical application which is hosted on another machine: that one didn't crash.

Do you have any suggestion/hint/tips/pointer?

Comment: Has c++ the same behavior by realloc/malloc of zerozised memblocks? maybe your handling with an zerosized memblock, as result of any calculations?

Comment: My guess: your heap is probably corrupted. The bug is somewhere else in the application; you are writing to freed memory or exceeding the length of a buffer or something similar. This randomly messes up your memory, and when the corruption hits a suitable location in the heap structures, `malloc` notices this and crashes.

Comment: A crash in any memory allocation / free routine is usually caused by memory corruption done much earlier, in totally different parts of the code/program. You should check SO for "memory corruption debug" or look into tools like valgrind.

Comment: @Zaibis as you can see, the method doesn't refer to external variables of any type other than function's arguments (which appear as valid), so I'm not sure of what you suggest to check.

Comment: Its in c99 the case, that if u do an malloc(0) or realloc() with size param 0, you can get returned an nonnull pointer which isnt allowed to get derefferenced because otherwise UB will appear. So maybe this is what happening that the allocating size is a variable identifier whcih gets zero in some callculations some where. and you hit such an non null adress. but this is just a uthopical suggestion .

Comment: @ others: I fear this is the only way, too bad I have to wait many days before it happens :-(

Comment: @Zaibis oh, I see. By checking $esp content, it seems that size param is not zero.

Comment: Why don't you try valgrind memcheck? It will report memory usage errors semi-automatically.

Comment: @keltar main problem is that production machines don't have valgrind installed.

Comment: That's bad... Still, valgrind could find something even if it isn't [yet] causing a failure, so using it on development machines periodically is very good idea.

Comment: @keltar and others: sure I'll give it a try.